# p:inputText (slow) getter call clears user value

Tags: jsf, input, jsf-2, primefaces

Did some searching (here and google) - can't find anything related, hoping someone has an idea.

While our application was running unusually slowly, we were seeing a bug where the user-entered value of a `<p:inputText id="searchNameInput" .../>` (located inside a `<p:overlayPanel>`) was clearing itself prior to user submission. From what I can tell, due to the application slowness, the user is able to enter a value prior to the initial getter call. This getter call then returns an empty String, effectively clearing the user-entered value.

Not sure how to solve this - open to any ideas.
Code snippet below.

**createSavedSearchBeanDialogue.xhtml**

```
        <p:outputPanel styleClass="save-search-panel-option" autoUpdate="true">
            <p:inputText id="searchNameInput" 
                         value="#{existingSavedSearchBean.searchNameToDisplay}"
                         styleClass="#{existingSavedSearchBean.inputTextStyleClass}"
                         widgetVar="wvsearchNameInput" size="55"
                         validatorMessage="#{msgs['search_results.operation.msg.error.search_name_empty']}"
                         disabled="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch 
                                     and !existingSavedSearchBean.saveAsACopy}">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="^(?=\s*\S).*$" />
            </p:inputText>
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:outputPanel styleClass="save-as-copy-panel">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="saveAsACopyCheckbox"
                                     widgetVar="wvSaveAsACopyCheckbox"
                                     value="#{existingSavedSearchBean.saveAsACopy}"
                                     rendered="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch}"
                                     styleClass="col-settings-panel-radio"
                                     process="@this"
                                     update="searchNameInput saveCurrentSearchButton" 
                                     disabled="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch 
                                                and !existingSavedSearchBean.currentSearchIsEditable}" >
                <p:ajax listener="#{existingSavedSearchBean.saveAsACopyCheckboxChanged}" 
                        update="searchNameInput saveCurrentSearchButton"/>
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

            <h:outputLabel for="saveAsACopyCheckbox"
                           value="#{msgs['search_results.save_search_panel.checkbox.save_as.label']}"
                           rendered="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="saveAsACopyCheckbox" styleClass="saved-search-overwritten-info"
                           value="#{msgs['search_results.save_search_panel.checkbox.save_as.not_overwritable.label']}"
                           rendered="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch and 
                                    !existingSavedSearchBean.currentSearchIsEditable}" />
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:outputPanel styleClass="save-as-copy-panel">                     
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="updatedSearchCriteriaCheckbox"
                                     widgetVar="wvUpdatedSearchCriteriaCheckbox"
                                     value="#{existingSavedSearchBean.useUpdatedSearchCriteria}"
                                     styleClass="col-settings-panel-radio"
                                     update="saveCurrentSearchButton"
                                     process="@this"
                                     rendered="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch 
                                                and existingSavedSearchBean.searchCriteriaHasChanged}" >
                <p:ajax update="saveCurrentSearchButton updatedColumnSettingsCheckbox"/>
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputLabel for="updatedSearchCriteriaCheckbox"
                           value="#{msgs['search_results.save_search_panel.checkbox.updated_criteria.label']}"
                           rendered="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch 
                                     and existingSavedSearchBean.searchCriteriaHasChanged}" />
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:outputPanel styleClass="save-as-copy-panel">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="updatedColumnSettingsCheckbox"
                                     widgetVar="wvUpdatedColumnSettingsCheckbox"
                                     value="#{existingSavedSearchBean.useUpdatedColumnSettings}"
                                     styleClass="col-settings-panel-radio"
                                     update="saveCurrentSearchButton"
                                     process="@this"
                                     rendered="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch 
                                                and existingSavedSearchBean.columnSettingsHaveChanged}" >
                <p:ajax update="saveCurrentSearchButton updatedSearchCriteriaCheckbox"/>
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputLabel for="updatedColumnSettingsCheckbox"
                           value="#{msgs['search_results.save_search_panel.checkbox.updated_column_settings.label']}"
                           rendered="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch 
                                      and existingSavedSearchBean.columnSettingsHaveChanged}" />
        </p:outputPanel>                
    </p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally ran across a solution - figured I'd post it in case anyone runs into a similar issue.
Setting `autoUpdate="false"` (rather than "true") on the enclosing `<p:outputPanel>` appears to eliminate the offending getter call.

```
<p:outputPanel styleClass="save-search-panel-option" autoUpdate="false">
            <p:inputText id="searchNameInput" 
                         value="#{existingSavedSearchBean.searchNameToDisplay}"
                         styleClass="#{existingSavedSearchBean.inputTextStyleClass}"
                         widgetVar="wvsearchNameInput" size="55"
                         validatorMessage="#{msgs['search_results.operation.msg.error.search_name_empty']}"
                         disabled="#{existingSavedSearchBean.resavingExecutedSavedSearch 
                                     and !existingSavedSearchBean.saveAsACopy}">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="^(?=\s*\S).*$" />
            </p:inputText>
        </p:outputPanel>
```